# jQuery 1.4 Dynamically created images aspect ratio incorrect in IE8 and max-width

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-1.4

After upgrading to jQuery 1.4, when I try to add an image to a page dynamically using jQuery 1.4 in IE8, the image will lose the correct aspect ratio. This appears to affect only IE8 (IE7 and Firefox work fine) with jQuery 1.4 (1.3.2 works fine). Including the jQuery compatability file does not fix the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Switching to 1.3.2 fixes the problem -->
    <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"
        type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var dynImg = $('<img></img>').attr('src', 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif');
            $('body').append(dynImg);
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        img
        {
            max-width: 5em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set CSS `zoom` property:

```
img {
    zoom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This did nothing to fix my problem.